# c++: Communicating a list of allowed classes which can be used

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two set of classes, say set `A = {a1, a2, a3}` all derived from `Asuper`,  and `B = {b1, b2}` all derived from `Bsuper`, and only the classes containing A and B can be used together (for eg. a1 and b2, or a3 and b1; they have logical dependencies). How can I communicate this to the users through a proper class design?

One way is to have enums associating with each classes and present them somewhere. Eg:

```
class LogicalGrouping{
enum gr1{A1, A2, A3};
enum gr2{B1, B2};

Asuper *a;
Bsuper *b;

setA(Asuper *a); //user can now manually check the types in gr1 and assign
setB(Bsuper *b);

};
```

But in my obvious opinion this is super ugly. One has to do manual decoding of the meaning of enums and assign them. I would have like to have something like a list of classes like `classlist {a1, a2, a3};`
Is there a cleaner way of doing it?

Comment: Well you could define something like `template <typename... Classes> struct classlist;` and instantiate it like `using gr1 = classlist<a1,a2,a3>;`, but I'm not sure what you mean to do with that list of classes.

Comment: What does it mean *used together*?

Comment: It is wise to first think about API, how will functions look like and how will they be called.

Comment: 'used together' means that in a program one has to use one the classes from `A` and other from `B`. There are can be several subclasses of `Asuper` and `Bsuper` respectfully, but I want the user to restrict (or communicate in a cleaner way) the usage of classes from set A and B only which are a subset of subclass(Asuper) and subclass(Bsuper). Not sure if this made any more clear.

Comment: I still don't understand your question entirely. What do you mean when you say only the classes that contain A and B? Give us an example of your original code. I assumed (wrongly, I presume), that you were interested in class deriving from both A and B. I also have a solution that checks whether the type exists in a type list (as @TartanLlama mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

Create two interfaces IA and IB let all A implement IA and all B implement IB then create a third interface IAB that inherits from both IA and IB. This will ensure that you have one of each.

When the user of your class wants to use your classes he needs to inherit from IAB which forces him to pick one A and one B.

Comment: Do you mean to have IA (and IB) as an intermediate class between the inheritance of Asuper and A, encoding the grouping information of class A? Sounds pretty nice to me. Will think about this design.

Answer (score 1):

This took a long time, but this is the code that I came up with, based on @TartanLlama's suggestion (more or less):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

//--- The class hierarchy
struct A{ virtual std::string name() const{ return "A";} };
struct B{ virtual std::string name() const{ return "B";} };

template <int i> struct An : A
{
  virtual std::string name() const{ return A::name() + std::to_string(i);}
};
template <int i> struct Bn : B
{
  virtual std::string name() const{ return B::name() + std::to_string(i);}
};
template <int i> struct AnBn : An<i>, Bn<i>
{
  virtual std::string name() const{ return An<i>::name() + Bn<i>::name(); }
};
template <int i,int j> struct AnBm : An<i>, Bn<j>
{
  virtual std::string name() const{ return An<i>::name() + Bn<j>::name(); }
};

//--- End of class hierarchy


//--- The magic that determines whether A/B is base of
template <class T> using A_is_base_of = 
    std::is_base_of<A,typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>;
template <class T> using B_is_base_of = 
    std::is_base_of<B,typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>;
template <class T> 
struct AB_is_base_of
{
  const static bool value = A_is_base_of<T>::value && B_is_base_of<T>::value;
  typedef typename std::integral_constant<bool,value>::type type;
};

//--- A tester - requires T has member function name... just for now...
struct IsAB_BaseOf
{
  template <class T>
    static void test(T&& value)
  {
    return test(std::forward<T>(value), 
      typename AB_is_base_of<T>::type());
  }

  private: template <class T>
    static void test(T&& value, std::true_type) 
    {
        std::cout << value.name() << " derives from both A and B" << std::endl;
    }
  private: template <class T>
    static void test(T&& value, std::false_type)
    {
        std::cout << value.name() << " does not derive from both A and B" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T> 
bool ab_IsBaseOf( T&& type )
{
  return AB_is_base_of<T>::value;
}

int main() {
  assert(!ab_IsBaseOf(An<0>()));
  assert(!ab_IsBaseOf(Bn<0>()));
  assert(!ab_IsBaseOf(Bn<0>()));
  assert(!ab_IsBaseOf(An<0>()));
  assert(!ab_IsBaseOf(An<0>()));
  assert(!ab_IsBaseOf(Bn<0>()));
  assert(ab_IsBaseOf(AnBn<0>()));
  assert(ab_IsBaseOf(AnBm<0,1>()));

  IsAB_BaseOf::test(AnBm<0,1>());
  IsAB_BaseOf::test(An<0>());
  IsAB_BaseOf::test(Bn<0>());
}

Output:
A0B1 derives from both A and B
A0 does not derive from both A and B
B0 does not derive from both A and B
```

Basically:

- Create a meta function that determines when A and B is base of T.
- Create a function template helper to call into the meta function
  conventiently (ab_IsBaseOf).
- Create the inheritance structure and    test...

The idea is that ab_IsBaseOf return true if A and B is the base of T.

EDIT:

One could with little effort create a type from the meta function, which you could use as argument to a function that would be called only if T is of the correct type (known as tag dispatching).

EDIT:

I've modified the presented source now to use tag dispatching select a function based on whether type T derives from A and B or not, which is what the OP wanted according to my understanding. Questions are welcome.

Comment: +1, two comments though: (i) in vour `ab_IsBaseOf` function, you should use a `std::remove_reference_t<T>` instead of a plain `T`. Otherwise, when you pass a reference to it, the type will be deduced as `T&` which fails in the `is_base_of` trait. (ii) I would better make it `constexpr` and then use `static_assert` instead of `assert`.
`

Comment: Wwerner Erasmus, did you just ask me to subclass both the set A and B from another class (AB here) to encode the information of the logical grouping (and a way to check that relation in the run time)? Sounds OK (this is same answer as CyberSock's) but I will have to think how good is it to introduce one another layer of class (AB here) to provide the grouping information.

Comment: @davidhigh. I will make the edits some time concerning the reference removal. Agreed. I'm aware of static assert. For small tests on ideone I prefer normal assert. I get they appeasing feeling when compilation doesn't fail ;). It seems rendering in the online compiler completes sooner when compilation successful...

Comment: @krips89, I merely created a class hierarchy for test purposes. I created A derivatives and B derivatives to ensure that they were not found, and AB derivatives (that would be found) of arbitrary type (by injecting non type template parameter). Then I verified all cases worked as expected. One could perform argument selection based on specialization.  My time was slightly constrained, I'll amend my post later.

Comment: @krips89. I've completed the solution. The class IsAB_BaseOf does exactly what you want, which is to discriminate when the type derives from both types (if I understand your requirement correctly).